# Bug in angular while running in development mode(live server)

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, localhost, liveserver

I'm fairly new to Angular and have a question about a bug when i work with the live server.
I'm currently using Angular version 17.2.0. I don't know where the error comes from and I'm contacting you in the hope that you have a solution.

I created the project without SSR in the hope that it would help. When it didn't work, i reinstalled vsCode and chrome with the extensions, angular and also restarted the PC. But the result remains the same.

[the problem in gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbst0.gif)